# SharePoint 2019 On Premise - Webhooks subscription with a private EndPoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, webhooks

I develop a REST MVC Webservice in .net C#, which is able to receive Webhook notifications from our internal SharePoint 2019. It works fine, when I test the application from Visual Studio 2019 with **Ngrok** but when I publish the service to an IIS web server internally, I still get the following error:

```
 {
     "odata.error": {
    
         "code": "-1, System.InvalidOperationException",
    
         "message": {
    
             "lang": "fr-FR",
    
             "value": "Failed to validate the notification url « https://xxxx.xxx.local/api/SPWebhook/HandleSharePointRequest » "
  
}
```

When I debug the Endpoint from IISExpress with Ngrok on my computer, everything works perfectly. The validation token is returned and SharePoint add the subscription correctly (based on official doc: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks). But when I publish this Endpoint to a Web Server IIS in our Private Domain I always received the error above.

If I use a Ngrok URL for the notification URL it works but when I use a domain URL servername.domain.local we always get the error.

Does the endpoint URL have to be public, **even for SharePoint On Premise** ? As with NGrok?

Many thanks in advance for your help!